# How do I rephrase this overly long descriptive sentence?

Tags: sentence-structure

I'm trying to describe the landscape of a dystopian city but I'm getting tripped up.

"The city is rather a hellish sight: the endless, monotonous rows of buildings are lit up by industrial powerhouses spewing flames into a murky night sky."

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Hi ethcoc, welcome to writing.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn about the cite. Unfortunately questions about rephrasing specific sentences are off-topic here as they are unlikely to help other writers. Therefore this question will be closed. If you [edit] it to a more general "how to keep descriptive sentences short in creative writing?" or similar it *may* get reopened. But you would need to be careful not to make the question too broad. Good luck and happy writing!

Comment: There are at least 2 sentences in there.

Comment: Don't get hung up on it right now. Write first, edit later. The more you write a find your voice, the better you will be at fixing these sort of sentences. As-is, it is 90% passable, so I wouldn't feel completely embarrassed handing it to an editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The City, endless rows of monotonous buildings back lit by the flames of industry spewing acrid murk into the starless night sky... a glimpse into hell itself.